# SCCM 2012 Perquisite Check "SQL Server service running Account Error"

Tags: sql-server, sccm, sccm-2007

Getting  """SQL Server service running Account Error"

Description as provided
"The logon account for the SQL Server service cannot be a local user account, NT SERVICE\ or LOCAL SERVICE.  You must configure the SQL Server service to use a valid domain account, NETWORK SERVICE, or LOCAL SYSTEM."
Tried to resolve by adding a domain user for SQL server and starting service with that account, didn't work.

Check screenshots.

1. [Error Screenshot during prequisite check](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O4xVh.png)
2. [I am already running the service as a Domain User](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hl3j9.png)

Couldn't manage to pass this check.

OS : Windows Server 2012
SQL Server : SQL Server 2012
SCCM : SCCM 2012

Answer (score 0):

**1. Install using at least SQL server standard version instead**

You have installed SQL server Express which is not supported for CAS/Primary site installation. Please use at least SQL server standard instead. For more details about SQL server 2012 requirement, please see below:

[image]

Here is the MS best practice for the account running SQL server service in ConfigMgr:

"Running the SQL Server service using the local system account of the SQL Server computer is not a SQL Server best practice. For the most secure operation of SQL Server site database servers, a low rights domain user account should be configured to run the SQL Server service."

**2. Create and register SPN**

When you configure a domain user as the account running SQL server service. You will also have to register the SPN to allow clients to identify and authenticate the service using Kerberos authentication. The command line registering the SPN:

To create an SPN for the NetBIOS name of the SQL Server use the following command: **setspn –A MSSQLSvc/:1433**

To create an SPN for the FQDN of the SQL Server use the following command: **setspn -A MSSQLSvc/:1433**